# android sqlite CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, create-table

Having a little problem with creating new tables. When I use the CREATE TABLE command my new tables form as they should, but when I exit the activity the app crashes and I get a TABLE ALREADY EXISTS in the logcat. If I use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS the new table isn't formed but just adds my new rows of data to a previous table and it doesn't crash. What is wrong with this? I would like to add the table without it giving me the already exists and I would like it to add without it adding rows to a different table.

SqliteHelper Class:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


public static final String TABLE_NAME = MainActivity.NameName;

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";
public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
public static final String COLUMN_LONG = "long";
public static final String COLUMN_RADI = "radi";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spraylogs.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



public static final String NEWTABLE = "CREATE TABLE  "
         + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
          + " text not null," + COLUMN_LAT+ ","  + COLUMN_LONG + "," + COLUMN_RADI +  ");";

public static final String SaveIt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
         + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
          + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
          + " text not null," + COLUMN_LAT+ ","  + COLUMN_LONG + "," + COLUMN_RADI +  ");";



 MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
  super(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
    "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NEWTABLE);

onCreate(db);
 } 

}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to work.  `CREATE TABLE` will throw an exception if the table already exists.  `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will create the table if it doesn't exist, or ignore the command if it does.  If you want it to delete the old table, use `DELETE TABLE IF EXISTS` before `CREATE TABLE`.  If you want to change the schema, use `ALTER TABLE`, not `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I don't understand why the CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is adding rows to the previous table.

Comment: It wouldn't, but if you have any code that does add a row, it would add it to that existing table-  CREATE IF NOT EXISTS doesn't delete the old data.

Answer (score -1):

I use it like this:

```
   internal static int checkTable()
    {
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbFileName + ";Version=3;");
            dbConn.Open();
            sqlCmd.Connection = dbConn;

            String makeTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS responde( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, sid TEXT, ans TEXT, answe TEXT, questid TEXT, timestamp TEXT)";

            sqlCmd.CommandText = makeTable;
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return 1;
        }
        catch (SQLiteException) { Console.WriteLine("Error DB 100"); return 0; }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) { Console.WriteLine("Error DB 101"); return 0; }
        catch (TypeInitializationException) { Console.WriteLine("Error DB 102"); return 0; }
    }
```