# Data insertion failed after wiped out app data emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

**Inserting data in SQlite from EditText**

Code was working well before i wiped out data from emulator now its giving me Null Pointer Exception, Kindly figure where actual problem lies. Thanks

[Data is being inserted from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHTNo.png)   ]

```
public long insert(String name, String password, String role, String unique) { 
    sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, name);
    contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password); 
    contentValues.put(KEY_ROLE, role); 
    contentValues.put(KEY_UNIQUE, unique); 
    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DOCTOR_TABLE, 
        null, 
        contentValues); 
    sqLiteDatabase.close(); 
    return result; 
}
```

[SQLite Database class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W1cE.png)

Comment: When your creating table in which your inserting ?

Comment: you can see the photo i have taken then screen shoot as well

Comment: yeah i saw that but i can't find where you have create table in which your inserting in

Comment: @NikhilSharma i've edited . sorry it was misplaced

Comment: i saw both of images but i can't find where your creating table

Comment: what is logcat error? can you post it also?

Comment: public long insert(String name, String password, String role, String unique) {
        sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, name);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(KEY_ROLE, role);
        contentValues.put(KEY_UNIQUE, unique);
        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DOCTOR_TABLE, null, contentValues);        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return result;
    }

Comment: @Exigente05 i have low reputation so i cant up 3rd pic here

Comment: @muhammadshahan you should not use images for code or for log/stack traces. You should copy and paste the code/log/staccktrace and then use the {} button to format it as code. e.g. as I've done with the code you placed in a comment.

Comment: @muhammadshahan you are far more likely to get help if you edit your question and then copy logcat/stacktrace, this will pinpoint where the null pointer exception(npe) occurred.

Comment: Solved Problem bro thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. It's an obvious. 
As you mentioned you have wiped the data, so the table which is located in the android app's own data folder will be deleted too. So you must check whether it exists or not.

Call to Getting your table returns null.
So you inserting your value to nothing.
So You can just alter the code to see if the table exists and if not create it.
Basically you just call, 
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838205/android-sqlite-create-table-if-not-exists)(SQLite 3.3 and above support IF NOT EXISTS). When you first call it, if not existed, it will create that table but later it will return the existing table with same name.

In one line- check or get the correct table before you do any operation.

Comment: Solved the problem

Comment: Good to hear it.